# Gmail clipping mail smaller than 102kb - any workarounds?

Tags: gmail, html-email, mailchimp

So I've coded my own html template for use in mailchimp. Ive been told that Gmail clips emails automatically after 102kb, so I made sure to keep the file quite small (76kb).
And yet for some reason, Gmail is still clipping the file!
Compiled (opening up the email in gmail, clicking "view entire email" and then hitting view source, brings up the email size to 86kb - *but* if I instead hit view original, and save that file, the size is 196kb!!!

What's causing the difference in Email size, which is the one that's important, and how can I make sure that my email stays at less than 102kb?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View Original is the one that is taken into account by Google, but I can't understand the difference between both without knowing more about your files.

We had the same issue with our emailView Original is the important one.

I can't understand the difference between both without knowing more about your files.

We had the same issue with our emails, and a good way to trim emails in our case was to remove useless line breaks and whitespace characters, which represented around 40% of our email size. So even without changing the structure of your email, trying to alleviate the HTML will probably keep you below the threshold, unless you have an extremely complex email.s, and a good way to trim emails in our cas